# Getting to main directory from subdomain folder via $_Server['document_root']

Tags: php, html, directory, apache2

So my folder is called 
leaguenotes and inside that folder i have a folder administration which is my subdomain folder so

```
leaguenotes
    -index.php
    -js
         -files.js
    -administration
         -index.php
         -otherfiles.php
```

And from administration index I'm trying to include in this example files.js with `<?php echo '<script src="'.dirname($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']).'/js/jquery.min.js"></script>'; ?>`

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = /var/www/html/leaguenotes/administration which is the subdomain folder so I'm using dirname to get to parent folder /var/www/html/leaguenotes and add /js/jquery.min.js and still the file is not found

Comment: are you accessing it via yor browser?

Comment: @Terradon the website yes, but it is on linux ubuntu 14.04 apache2 server

Answer (score 0):

if you access your page, take a look at the html source-code, i think you will see the source produced from your php code is not the correct one. because a real subdomain is a different domain then your domain itself. It is treated by your browser as a different domain.

Comment: <script src="/var/www/html/leaguenotes/js/jquery.min.js"></script> this is what is being generated which is the right directory

Comment: it ain't....for your server it is ok, but this path is not accessable for your browser....it should become a relative path from your page but that is not possible,because your main domain is a different domain for your browser. So you need an absolute link to your main domain. Or you copy your js file to your subdomain and then a releative url can be used.

Comment: is there no other way? Because I would want the same code to work for my local server so I wouldn't have to change files all the time and duplicating files doesn't seem like a smart idea since If i make changes I would have to remember to always copy the file to 2 locations

Comment: then in your subdomain, just hardcode the link to your main domain.This way you have just 1 location to maintaine and in fact you are using it as a kind of CDN (content deleivery network). So visitors can use a cached js version if they have visited your pages before.

Comment: I really thought there would be easier more intuitive way of accessing those files that would work both on my localhost and on my server so I wouldn't have to do any extra work.

Comment: you need to understand how webservers deliver their content. and how browsers deal with subdomains. It is not about the path inside your server-computer,it is all about the path from the public root of your website, So, sub.domain.com  is for your browser totally different then domain.com. Internally it is possible to deliver the same content, but then you need rules in your .htaccess file. Also the fact that you are using a local machine, your browser dont care, it is just requesting a page from localhost:8080/yourpage.php and that is a connection with your own webserver.

Comment: I think the easiest way for me to deal with it would be to create an if statement checking the domain that I'm on and then either include http://domain/js files or /www/html/domain/js files

Comment: ok, just try and if it fails, edit your post and show some more code.

Comment: I've created another question with new problems still including files is an issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33174435/http-request-failed-when-including-file-through-url-from-subdomain/33175040?noredirect=1#comment54157753_33175040