# Http request failed when including file through url from subdomain

Tags: php, html, directory, apache2

I'm trying to make reliable code that will work both on my local server and on my actual server for website so I won't have to change paths etc. to my files. I cannot use relative paths since I'm using a subdomain so browser doesn't see folders above that path so what I'm trying to do is on my local server use root folder to guide my code where the files are and on webserver I retrive servername. The error that I get right now is

```
Warning: include(http://cms.domain.com/serverdetails.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/html/domain/administration/cms/DBconnection_patches.php on line 11
```

I have main domain and a subdomain cms.domain with cms files are structured like so

```
domain
    -index.php
    -js
         -files.js
    -administration (subdomain folder)
         -index.php
         -otherfiles.php
```

It is a normal subdomain made through Vhost, on linux ubuntu 14.04 apache2.

```
  if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='domain.com'){
            $local = false; 
        }elseif($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=='localhost'){
            $local = true;
        }
        if($local){
            include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/domain/administration/serverdetails.php';
        }else{
            include 'http://cms.'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/serverdetails.php';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude you ***cannot*** include a `.php` file using absolute URLS!!!

Since while generating the URL the server(Apache/nginx/whatever) is supposed to not output the content of the file, **(if properly configured)**. Instead it it supposed to execute the file and return the output of the executed code.

You shall need to use the internal `file path` to include the file.
And for that `dirname(__FILE__)` shall be useful in calculating the `relative path`.

Comment: Would you mind giving an example I still do not fully understand that. I don't think I can use internal file path when calling from domain a subdomain

Comment: If you mean to say that the file is not present in the current directory then you can actually build relative paths by using the double dots to navigate upwards in the directory, and If you say that the said file is not accessible to you whatsoever on the subdomain then why not just copy past it into the subdomains accessible directory.

Comment: Because I don't want to duplicate files, later on I'll make some changes to those files and I will not remember to always copy it to 2 directories it will make a mess. Relative path doesn't work because a browser can not get to a folder that is cms.domain.com before that it can only get further in folders.

Comment: Dude, your basic understanding of how things work in serverside scripting is flawed..

The included file is not "included by the browser" it is being included by the php interpreter, during runtime and all this is happening before the browser even gets the first bit of response. ...

Comment: include(../serverdetails.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/leaguenotes/administration/cms/DBconnection_patches.php on line 11 after trying relative path and here is also a quote from similar question 'browsers deal with subdomains. It is not about the path inside your server-computer,it is all about the path from the public root of your website, So, sub.domain.com is for your browser totally different then domain.com. Internally it is possible to deliver the same content, but then you need rules in your .htaccess file.'